# "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" trying to install IBM_DB library in Anaconda Jupyter notebook: IBM_HTTP_Server at public.dhe.ibm.com Port 443

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

While trying to install ibm_db library to connect to my Db2 database on Cloud in Anaconda Jupyter notebook I got the error message "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden". When I tried to go to the link for ntx64_odbc_cli.zip in the error message manually I found out that I don't have permission to access that site (https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ntx64_odbc_cli.zip) indeed. Tell me please what should I do to resolve this problem?

The very command was:

```
!pip install --force-reinstall ibm_db==3.1.0 ibm_db_sa==0.3.3
```

Result:
Collecting ibm_db==3.1.0
Using cached ibm_db-3.1.0.tar.gz (797 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

[29 lines of output]
Detected 64-bit Python
Downloading [https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ntx64_odbc_cli.zip](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 363, in 
main()
File "C:\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 345, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "C:\Conda\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
File "C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bb793z8p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
File "C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bb793z8p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\micro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bb793z8p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 240, in 
File "C:\Conda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Conda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Conda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
File "C:\Conda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Conda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Conda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

Comment: we are using pip version 22.0.4 and python 3.9

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofawX.png

Has anyone found a workaround or is it an intermittent issue?